Quasar Capacitor app looking for image in wrong location
I have made capacitor app from quasar and its not loading images when i use build command but works in dev the error i am getting is its looking for image in wrong location, like i have a component who's route is '/explore/program/:id' so the image used in all the components are in assets folder, when i use quasar dev command for android app it works fine but when i use build command for android app it doesnt show image and gives error 404 for 'https://localhost/explore/program/img/476cf7b489924c7e9ab098f381a8d71e.svg' clearly its looking for it in wrong location. Can anyone help with this. i am using quasar 2 vue 3
I tried importing images as a vue component but as there are so many images so its not possible to include all images as components.
